# Overflowing Box: Enable Scroll If Two Fingers, Disable If One (Like Google Maps Does With gestureHandling)

Tags: javascript, touch

I'm trying to do the same as Google Maps recently implemented when embedding a map on a website.

**If the user starts scrolling over the box, a message shows up telling him to use two fingers to scroll through the box.**
This is easy to do.

**Once the user starts scrolling over the box with two fingers, enable the scroll.**
To do this, I thought simply changing from `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: scroll;` would do, but it doesn't: the `touchmove` event is indeed fired when two fingers are moving over that box, but no scrolling occurs, even with `overflow: scroll` previously set on `touchstart`. However, if on page load, the scroll box is already set to `overflow: scroll`, scrolling with two fingers is not an issue.

I'd like to use the browser's native scroll. Any idea on how to achieve this?